# ARGB Color Format

Tags: java-me

Does Java ME support 0xAARRGGBB color format? I mean can I change the opacity of an image by modifying the alpha value of pixels? I work with Graphics and Image classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will undoubtedly vary between devices.  Why not just try it and see?

Edit:  OK so I guess you want to know actually how to do it.  The method you will need is [`Image.getRGB()`](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Image.html#getRGB%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) -- as per the docs:

> Obtains ARGB pixel data from the
>   specified region of this image and
>   stores it in the provided array of
>   integers. Each pixel value is stored
>   in 0xAARRGGBB format, where the
>   high-order byte contains the alpha
>   channel and the remaining bytes
>   contain color components for red,
>   green and blue, respectively. The
>   alpha channel specifies the opacity of
>   the pixel, where a value of 0x00
>   represents a pixel that is fully
>   transparent and a value of 0xFF
>   represents a fully opaque pixel.

Modify the pixels you want then use the data to create a new image using [`Image.createRGBImage()`](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Image.html#createRGBImage%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29).

Edit: The spec says that all devices should allow alpha manipulation.

One way to tell whether they do or not is to [create a mutable image](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Image.html#createImage%28int,%20int%29), g[et its graphics object](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Image.html#getGraphics%28%29), [write some ARGB data to it](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Graphics.html#drawRGB%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29), then [read it back](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Image.html#getRGB%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), and see if the alpha data is still present; if not then you can bet alpha transparency is not supported.

The methods I've linked to should be all you need to do this, the actual method I leave as an exercise ;)

Comment: I'm developing a generic application for all devices that support MIDP 2.0,so I'm not limited to specific device model. My purpose is to create glass effect by modifying opacity value. What's your suggestion?

Comment: +1 for document, But What if the target device does not support alpha value? I need to change it in order to create an opaque image.

Comment: Is that really correct!  Didn't know that.  Have 10 on me ;)    According to the spec I've posted, every device should support ARGB.  However experience has taught me this is not always the case with J2ME.  I'll edit the answer to include a way of finding out...

Comment: I'll work on the solution you provided and let you know of the results and I'll do the exercise:)

Comment: Ok. Having implemented your proposed solution, I could discover whether the target device supports alpha manipulation or not. What if it does not support? I'm looking for a solution to actually simulate this behaviour(maiking an opaque image). What's your suggestion then? I'm approaching 15 reputation:)